# Boundary Traversal of the binary tree

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

**Can anyone help me in figuring out the bug in this code it works perfectly fine for some test cases but fails in several test cases like**

*1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 -1 -1 3 10 11 13 -1 1 -1 10 11 8 -1 -1 -1 5 -1 -1 -1 5 -1 -1 8 -1 -1 9 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1*

Where every -1 represents a null Node

```
public class boundaryTraversal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        BinaryTreeNode node = takeInput(sc);
    //1 2 4 6 -1 -1 7 -1 -1 -1 3 -1 5 -1 -1
  if (node == null){
            return arr;
        }
        arr.add(node.data);
        ArrayList<Integer> arrLeft = left(node, arr);
        ArrayList<Integer> arrLeaf = leafNode(node, arr);

        ArrayList<Integer> arrRight = right(node, arr);
        System.out.println(arr);

    }
   public static ArrayList<Integer> left(BinaryTreeNode root, ArrayList<Integer> arr){
        if (root == null){
            return arr;
        }
        if (root.left != null  && root.left.left != null){
            arr.add(root.left.data);
        }
        else if (root.right != null && root.right.right != null){
            arr.add(root.right.data);
        }
        left(root.left, arr);
        return arr;
    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> leafNode(BinaryTreeNode root, ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
        if (root == null){
            return arr;
        }
        if (root.left == null && root.right == null){
            arr.add(root.data);
        }
        leafNode(root.left, arr);
        leafNode(root.right, arr);
        return arr;
    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> right(BinaryTreeNode root, ArrayList<Integer> arr){
        if (root == null){
            return arr;
        }
        left(root.right, arr);
        if (root.right != null  && root.right.right != null){
            arr.add(root.right.data);
        }
        else if (root.left != null && root.left.left != null){
            arr.add(root.left.data);
        }

        return arr;
    }
    }
```

Comment: what is the bug? what you want to do?

Comment: Please define what "boundary" of a tree is.

Comment: Without a proper description of what the task is, we cannot help you. Add a link to the code challenge, and quote it literally, so we have all information on what this task is about.

Comment: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/boundary-traversal-of-binary-tree/1
You can check this, It is the same question

Besides that also don't mind the takeInput function in the main function I was using that when I was trying to solve in my IDE
 GFG has. his own input function you only need to return the List.

Comment: Links are interesting, but please edit your question and *include* the information inline. There should not be any essential information behind a link only. Also make the problem reproducible. We should not have to add any code ourselves to make it run and reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issues:

- In `left`, `if (root.left != null  && root.left.left != null)` seems to want to check that there is a left child that is *not a leaf*, but if `root.left.left` is null, there could still be a `root.left.right` that is not null, so this could exclude some nodes that are on the "left side".
- In `left`, `else if (root.right != null && root.right.right != null)` has a similar problem as above (but mirrored), but it also assumes that `root.left` is null. This is not guaranteed. If there is a `node.left` which is a leaf, then we also get in the `else` part, yet at this point we should stop adding nodes in the array, as we leave the "left side" of the tree.
- The `right` function has similar problems as above, but also, it is not recursive. It calls `left` instead of `right`.

In my opinion, your code became a bit more complex than necessary, when trying to avoid that the functions `left` or `right` would output *leaves*, as those are already output by the function `leafNode`.

I would take a different approach to avoid outputting the same node twice: perform the recursive search like you do in the function `leafNode`, but pass two extra booleans which indicate whether you are on the "left side" or whether you are on the "right side" of the tree, (or neither). It is not so hard to determine these booleans for the recursive call, and so you can propagate that information throughout the tree and decide whether to output the node or not.

Here is a spoiler implementation of that idea, which follows the GeeksForGeeks version of the challenge:

> `ArrayList<Integer> boundary(Node node) {
>          ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
>          if (node != null) {
>              arr.add(node.data);
>              dfs(node.left, true, false, arr);
>              dfs(node.right, false, true, arr);
>          }
>          return arr;
>      }
>
>      void dfs(Node node, boolean onLeft, boolean onRight, ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
>          if (node != null) {
>              boolean isLeaf = node.left == null && node.right == null;
>              if (onLeft || isLeaf) {
>                  arr.add(node.data);
>              }
>              dfs(node.left, onLeft, onRight && node.right == null, arr);
>              dfs(node.right, onLeft && node.left == null, onRight, arr);
>              if (onRight && !isLeaf) {
>                  arr.add(node.data);
>              }
>          }
>      }`